# How to handle some function with if statement using Powershell?

Tags: function, powershell

I want to handle my function with if statement. I tried this code, but it always return me the value of `$End_F` which is `"BB"` even my file contains of `"@AB@CD"` . Anyone can help, please.

The file that I look for "@AB@CD" is like this.

```
Config
;     Date="2019/06/12" Time="10:25:02" UTC="0"
;
Number
    123456@AB@CD
```

---

```
$Get_SKU = Get-Content '.\Number.txt' | Where-Object {$_.Contains("@AB@CD")}
$Get_SKU
if($Get_SKU)
{$ML = "1"
    AUTO_SELECT
}
else
{   
    END_Proc
}


Function AUTO_SELECT
{
    $AT = "AA"
    $AT
}

Function END_Proc
{
$End_F = "BB"
$End_F
}
$FE_UB = "4"
if($ML = "1" -and $FE_UB -eq $true)
{ 
    G_BEGIN
}

if($ML = "1" -and $FE_UB -eq $false)
{ 
    G_END
}

else
{
    END_Proc

    }

Function G_BEGIN
{
$begin = "Ready"
$begin
}

Function G_END
{
$ending = "Stop"
$ending
}
```

Comment: `.Contains()` is case-sensitive. Are you accounting for lowercase `@ab@cd`? If case does not matter, you could just use `-match`, e.g. `| where {$_ -Match '@ab@cd'}`.

Comment: I just accounting for uppercase.

Comment: You should change the if statement as well to `if ($Get_SKU)` because $Get_SKU will never equal $true. It will equal the string that meets the where condition. If you absolutely need a $true result, you need to either use `-Match` on a single string or cast the result to boolean `[bool]$Get_SKU`, which could have undesirable results in specific cases.

Comment: I change the `if ($Get_SKU)` and It works. 
But my problem now in this part `$FE_UB = "4"
if($ML = "1" -and $FE_UB -eq $true)
{ 
    G_BEGIN
}

if($ML = "1" -and $FE_UB -eq $false)
{ 
    G_END
}

else
{
    END_Proc

    }

Function G_BEGIN
{
$begin = "Ready"
$begin
}

Function G_END
{
$ending = "Stop"
$ending
}`

Comment: If you are not setting anything to `$true` or `$false` in the code, you should not compare the variables against those values. Those are boolean types. 4 is an integer (Int32 by default) value type. `"data"` is a string type. If you are going to do comparisons, you need to use like types, i.e. don't compare an integer or string to a boolean.

Comment: in addition to using `-match` to avoid case problems, you REALLY should define functions _before you use them_. powershell scans code from the beginning to the end ... and you are trying to use functions _before they are defined_. that is problematic at best. [*grin*]

Comment: `=` is not an acceptable comparison operator in an if statement. You should replace `=` in your if statements with `-eq`. `=` is used for assignment. If your intention is to assign a value to a variable, then do that outside of the `if (condition)`. Instead do it within the script block `{ }` of the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things need to be corrected to make your code work as expected.

```
Function AUTO_SELECT
{
    $AT = "AA"
    $AT
}

Function END_Proc
{
    $End_F = "BB"
    $End_F
}

Function G_BEGIN
{
    $begin = "Ready"
    $begin
}

Function G_END
{
    $ending = "Stop"
    $ending
}

$Get_SKU = Get-Content '.\Number.txt' | Where-Object {$_.Contains("@AB@CD")}
$Get_SKU
if($Get_SKU)
{   
    $ML = "1"
    AUTO_SELECT
}
else
{   
    END_Proc
}

$FE_UB = "4"
if($ML -eq "1" -and $FE_UB)
{ 
    G_BEGIN
}

if($ML -eq "1" -and !$FE_UB)
{ 
    G_END
}

else
{
    END_Proc

}
```

**Explanation of Changes:**

- `$Get_SKU` will store either `$null` or a string depending on whether the `Where-Object` condition finds a match. As a result, I swapped out `if ($Get_SKU -eq $true)` in favor of `if ($Get_SKU)`. This change will result in a `$true` evaluation if `$Get_SKU` is not `$null`.
- I moved the functions to the top of the script because PowerShell executes the code starting from top to bottom. It is not compiled first. So you can't make a function call ***BEFORE*** the function has been read into memory and defined.
- `if ($ML = "1" -and $FE_UB -eq $true)` has been updated to `if ($ML -eq "1" -and $FE_UB)` because variable assignment `variable = value` should not happen in an if statement condition. If you are comparing values, the proper operator here is `-eq`. Regarding `$FE_UB`, the same explanation applies as in the `$Get_SKU` changes.
- `$FE_UB -eq $false` was changed to `!$FE_UB`. The removal of the `-eq $false` operator is based on the explanation given for `$Get_SKU`. The `!` character is used to effectively `-not` the result. This will turn the value into a boolean value and then output the opposite boolean response. For example, `!"string data"` will output `$False`. `!$null` will output `$True`. I hope this part is clear.

**Further Insight:**

- `$True` and `$False` evaluations

  - You can make just about anything return a boolean value. Three such ways include using casting, the `-as` operator, and `!`. There are many other ways and hacks to do this.

    - Casting:

      ```
      $get_sku = "data"
      [boolean]$get_sku
      True
      ```
    - `-as` Operator:

      ```
      $get_sku = $null
      $get_sku -as [boolean]
      False
      ```
    - Fun with `!`:

      ```
      $get_sku = 4
      !$get_sku
      False
      !!$get_sku
      True
      ```